# how to save to scraped data to mongodb database

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, dataframe

I have different ideas of saving each of my output to a database and with a key factor of mongodb expecting a dictionary data type to be passed in before your items can be save in mongo collection.

my datas are coming from this function which i was able to print out easily after a if condition

```
article_text, summary_sentences, entity_names, categorized_data, max_img, keywords = get_article_metadata(article_url, reject_p_tags, num_sents_in_summary, sentence_threshold)
                    print(summary_sentences)
                    print(article_title)
                    print('%s at %s:00' % (published_date, hour))
                    print('Entity Names', entity_names)
                    print('Categorized data', categorized_data)
                    print('Top images', max_img)
                    print('Keyowrds', keywords)
```

how can I easily save this to a dataframe, because I can easily convert the dataframe to a dictionary and then insert into the mongodb in that order

This is an example of the output but here I have append this to list of dictionary

```
[{'title': 'Shahrukh Birthday Countdown, Trimurti! Anil and Jackie and Shahrukh, Oh My!!!!', 'publish_date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 24), 'Summary': ['Anil stills milk and toys for the baby, Jackie yells at him for teaching the baby bad values, lil’ Anil ends up running away from home.', 'He has such zest for life and just wants to share it, none of that boring rules and advice that Jackie gave out.', 'Childish Shahrukh with Jackie felt like a 60 year old talking to a 6 year old, Anil and Shahrukh feels more like a 25 year old and 18 year old, the characters they are actually playing.'], 'Article_category': 'Entertainment', 'image_links': ['https://dontcallitbollywood.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/cropped-akbar.jpg', 'https://d1ba50i68eftrl.cloudfront.net/images/Artifact_Data/CINE/CINE-pos/.resized_img_s3/medium/1018695.CINE.pos.jpg'], 'keywords': ['ghai likes symbolism', 'put shahrukh ’', 'deep character work', 'highly stylized plots', 'two styles sets']}]
```

Thanks in advance